# Perl Regex to match alphanumeric

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to kernel & gcc version by reading /proc/version file using Perl. But I am not sure but the regex to match the versions. I tried something like this

```
/Linux version (\d+)*gcc version(\d+)*/
```

But its not working. Thanks in advance. I am newbie to Perl. And the contents of version is

> Linux version 2.6.32-21-generic (buildd@rothera) (gcc version 4.4.3
>   (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:10:02 UTC 2010

Comment: The answer of Narendra Yadala is correct, I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$version =~ /Linux version ([\d.-]+)-\D.*gcc version ([\d.]+) /;
print "Linux version: $1\ngcc version: $2\n";
```

The output:

```
Linux version: 2.6.32-21
gcc version: 4.4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for you

```
/Linux version ([\w.-]*).*?gcc version ([\w.]*)/
```

First captured group will have linux version `2.6.32-21-generic` and second captured group will have gcc version `4.4.3`. If you do not want to capture `generic` then use `\d` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

```
m{Linux version\s(\S+).*gcc version\s(\S+)} and print "$1\n$2\n"
```